# How do I include shader functions from a package in a unity shader? (built-in pipeline)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shaderlab

I have installed the package NoiseShaders (https://github.com/keijiro/NoiseShader.git) via the package manager in Unity. It shows up as installed in my package manager.

My question is how do I use its functions in my shader? Do I include something, and if so, how do I include something from the package manager to my shader?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should include these files in your shader

```
#include "Packages/jp.keijiro.noiseshader/Shader/ClassicNoise2D.hlsl"
#include "Packages/jp.keijiro.noiseshader/Shader/ClassicNoise3D.hlsl"
#include "Packages/jp.keijiro.noiseshader/Shader/SimplexNoise2D.hlsl"
#include "Packages/jp.keijiro.noiseshader/Shader/SimplexNoise3D.hlsl"
```

Then you can call one of these functions:

```
ClassicNoise(coord);
PeriodicNoise(coord, period);
SimplexNoiseGrad(coord);
SimplexNoise(coord);
```

From what looks like an example shader in the package, here:
https://github.com/keijiro/NoiseShader/blob/master/Assets/Visualizer.shader